# getting directory of files excluding parent folder name

Tags: command-line, directory, find

I want to get the names of directories containing particular files but exclude the parent directory name.

For example:

```
find ./app -name '*.component.html';
```

When I use this command, it returns the results shown below:

```
./app/register/register.component.html
./app/_directives/alert.component.html
./app/app.component.html
./app/home/home.component.html
./app/login/login.component.html
```

But I want to get the results without `./app`. It can be done by entering the `app` directory, like this:

```
cd app; find -name '*.component.html';

./register/register.component.html
./_directives/alert.component.html
./app.component.html
./home/home.component.html
./login/login.component.html
```

But I want to do it with a single command, without entering `app`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `find`, you can use

```
find ./app -name '*.component.html' -printf '%P\n'
```

From the `-printf` section of `man find`:

```
    %P     File's name with the name  of  the  starting-point  under
           which it was found removed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably using `%P` as @steeldriver suggested. Alternatively, you could parse the output to remove the name:

```
$ find ./app -name '*.component.html' | sed 's#\./app/#./#'
./app.component.html
./home/home.component.html
./_directives/alert.component.html
./login/login.component.html
./register/register.component.html
```

Or, you could run the whole thing in a subshell, and cd into `./app` in the subshell so your actual working directory remains unchanged:

```
$ pwd 
/home/terdon
$ ( cd app; find -name '*.component.html')
./app.component.html
./home/home.component.html
./_directives/alert.component.html
./login/login.component.html
./register/register.component.html
$ pwd
/home/terdon
```

Finally, you could also use the shell instead of `find` ()assuming you're using bash):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ printf '%s\n' ./app/**/*component.html |  sed 's#\./app/#./#'
./app.component.html
./_directives/alert.component.html
./home/home.component.html
./login/login.component.html
./register/register.component.html
```

Or

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for f in ./app/**/*component.html ; do echo "${f%./app}"; done
./app/app.component.html
./app/_directives/alert.component.html
./app/home/home.component.html
./app/login/login.component.html
./app/register/register.component.html
```